# Не выбирается значение в ComboboxEditor в Xceed PropertyGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, propertygrid

Доброго времени суток!

Создал объект, который должен редактироваться в PropertyGrid, в сторону от редактора в объект, все данные нормально попадают. А вот в обратную сторону, когда объект обновляется, то в редакторе не обновляются данные.

Т.е. Если в комбобоксе я выберу нужный регион, то в объект он поместится. А вот если в объекте изменю регион - то в комбобоксе он не изменяется и сбрасывается на пустой.

Не понимаю куда дальше копать.

Редактор описан так:

```
public class FieldsComboboxEditor : ComboBoxEditor
   {
            protected override IEnumerable CreateItemsSource(PropertyItem propertyItem)
            {
    //Здесь загружаем данные и выдаем список
                return mylist;
            }
    }
```

Сам объект привязывается так:

```
 <tk:PropertyGrid Grid.Row="1" DataContext="{Binding}" SelectedObject="{Binding DBInfo}" AutoGenerateProperties="True">
        </tk:PropertyGrid>
```

Объект DBinfo выглядит упрощенно так:

```
public class DBInfoViewModel : Vm
{
private FieldViewModel _Region;
        [Category("Основные")]
        [DisplayName("Регион (REGION)")]
        [Description("Регион принадлежности базы")]
        [ExpandableObject]
        [Editor(typeof(FieldsComboboxEditor), typeof(FieldsComboboxEditor))]
        public FieldViewModel Region
        {
            get => _Region;
            set => Set(ref _Region, value, nameof(Region));
        }
}
```

Ну и объект редактируемого поля выглядит следующим образом:

```
public class FieldViewModel : Vm
    {
        private string _SKey;
        [ReadOnly(true)]
        [DisplayName("Ключ")]
        [Description("Уникальный идентификатор")]
        [Browsable(false)]
        public string SKey
        {
            get => _SKey;
            set => Set(ref _SKey, value, nameof(SKey));
        }

        private string _SValue;
        [ReadOnly(true)]
        [DisplayName("Значение")]
        [Description("Значение элемента")]
        public string SValue
        {
            get => _SValue;
            set => Set(ref _SValue, value, nameof(SValue));
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return $"{SKey} - {SValue}";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Раз он скидывается, значит binding срабатывает. Возможно, дело в объекте, который вы выбираете. Он точно из той коллекции, которая забинжена на контрол?

Comment: Класс тот же, но объект новый, создается заново. А как произвести сопоставление в этом случае? Достаточно проблематично добраться в место присвоения значения до списка, который в комбобоксе содержится.

Comment: Почитайте про то, как переопределяется сравнение объектов класса. Equals, GetHashCode, ToString() - вот это вам надо переопределять.